# Ensurepip module not existing, how to install manually?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.8, python-venv, synology

In the interest of not getting an XY problem: the goal is to create a virtual environment *on synology dsm, so no apt-get*, where pip is installed manually.

I am trying to create a virtual environment, in above environment (synology dsm package python 3.8 with pip installed manually).

However this gives the following error:

```
$ python3 -m venv new_venv
Error: Command '['/volume1/docker/builder/new_venv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

In the chain of finding that error I discovered that `venv` is working "just fine":

```
$ python3 -m venv --without-pip new_venv
```

Works as expected. Also pip itself works as expected. However I had to install pip manually. This also has as consequence that the synology dsm version of python does not have the module `ensurepip`..

```
# python3 -c "import ensurepip; print(ensurepip.__file__);"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ensurepip'
```

This gives the problem: how does one manually install `ensurepip`, and/or make virtual env install `pip` without relying on `ensurepip`?

Comment: @phd yes pip is installed through that and correctly works - it's that `venv` depends on `ensurepip` which isn't installed.

Answer (score 4):

### Install pip inside your venv virtual environment

Download the newest pip installation script and name the file get-pip.py:

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Create the virtual environment with Python 3 but without pip inside it (assuming you are in `/volume1/docker/builder/`):

```
$ python3 -m venv --without-pip /volume1/docker/builder/new_venv
```

Activate the virtual environment:

```
$ source /volume1/docker/builder/new_venv/bin/activate
```

Your prompt should now contain the virtual environment name in parens:

```
(new_venv) $
```

The script will install pip inside the ***activated*** venv virtual environment:

```
(new_venv) $ python get-pip.py
# or
(new_venv) $ python3 get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu, it seems the module is not installed by default when installing Python. I managed to get it working by running

```
# Adjust for your python version
sudo apt-get install python3.8-venv
```